# what's the behaviour of an async function containing an await and a return statement together

Tags: javascript, async-await, return

```
async function f() {
  let result = await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve("done after 1sec"), 1000)); //(*)

  console.log(result);

  return Promise.resolve("done immediately");  //(**)
}

f().then((result) => console.log(result));

console.log("synchronous code");
```

My understanding as per the moment on this code is that:

1:The sting *synchronous code* will be logged first

2:followed by the execution of .then handler logging
*done after asynchronous code*, since function f   returned an already resolved promise

3:And after 1sec the awaited promise inside function
f will be resolved and *done* will be logged.

But what am getting is:

1:synchronous code.

2: done after 1sec.

3: done after asynchronous code.

is as if the promise returned on line * is hindering the promise on line ** from resolving before it.

what am i over looking? Thanks in advance for any support

Comment: The `console.log(result);` in your `f()` is executed before `return Promise.resolve("done immediately");`. Why would you expect `"done after 1sec"` to be logged last?

Comment: "*since function f returned an already resolved promise*" - no, it doesn't. The `return` statement in the function has not yet been executed, the code is still waiting for the first promise. The `async function` creates and returns an *unresolved* promise as soon as the function is called.